# Array initialization gives null pointer exception

Tags: java

I am learning Java recently and was trying to work with classes.But I am not able to initialize array objects

```
 class Tablet
 {
    String S = null;
    void set(String a)
    {
        S = a;
    }
}

public class questions
{

public static void main(String args[])
{

    Tablet[] T = new Tablet[6];
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
    {
        T[i].set("111"); // I get null pointer exception here
    }

    //solution(T,6);
} 
}
```

can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Initializing an array does not create new objects at each index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
Tablet[] T = new Tablet[6];
```

You are creating **array of references(i.e Array of reference variables)** which are not pointing to anywhere else i.e they are null.You need to assign objects to above created reference variables in array.

```
Tablet[] T = new Tablet[6];
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
    {
        T[i]=new Tablet();
        T[i].set("111"); // No Null Pointer Exception Now
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the indexes of array

```
class Tablet {

    String S = null;

    void set(String a) {
        S = a;
    }
}

class questions {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Tablet[] T = new Tablet[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            T[i] = new Tablet();
            T[i].set("111"); // I get null pointer exception here
        }

        //solution(T,6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You created an array (a holder for several `Tablet` objects), but you didn't actually create any `Tablet`s to go inside it. Right now, `T` (which really should be lowercase; `T` looks like both a constant and a type parameter) has the following contents:

```
T: {null, null, null, null, null, null}
```

You need to create `new Tablet`s and put them inside your array, perhaps like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length /* don't hardcode the size twice */; i++) {
    array[i] = new Tablet();
    array[i].set("111");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the array. But, the elements in the array point to null. So obviously, if you try to call a method on a null pointer, you'll be getting a null pointer exception.
You have to initialize every object in the array using the new keyword.

You have to add a T[i] = new Tablet(); to initialize the variable before performing any function on it.

```
T[i]=new Tablet();
T[i].set("111");
```

Do this inside the for loop